# bash is replacing colon with space, how do I keep the colons?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to echo a compatible MySQL datetime wit bash and it keeps replacing the colons with spaces.

Any ideas on how I can prevent them from being replaced?

Also, I have tried to replace the spaces with sed back into colons, but they still come out as spaces, what is the deal here?

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
EXECUTED=$(php evaluate.php $now)
```

Exepected Result: 2012-12-08 06:34:00

evaluate.php

```
var_dump($argv)
```

Comment: It works as expected for me. How are you running the script? Check if your shell is displaying colons properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes around the argument to your PHP script to preserve the space in a single argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
EXECUTED=$(php evaluate.php "$now")
```

Whether that's sufficient is another matter.  Your PHP script seems to be missing the PHP tags.

```
$ php evaluate.php "$now"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "evaluate.php"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2012-12-07 22:39:46"
}
$
```

#### evaluate.php

```
<?php
var_dump($argv)
?>
```